# DOMPDF cant output values in html file

Tags: php, dompdf

This is probably a newbie question. I want to create pdf from user input merged with a fixed template.

The code of the fixed template is

```
<body>
<div>
<?php echo $request['firstname'];?>
<?php echo $request['lastname'];?>
</div>
</body>
```

The PHP file that generate PDF contains

```
$request=array('firstname'=>$_POST['firstname'], 'lastname'=>$_POST['lastname']);

ob_start();
require_once ('pdf-template/invoice.php');
$template = ob_get_clean();

require_once ('dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('$template');

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream();
```

If I echo the output of $template, then I can see

> firstname lastname

But the generated PDF file contains only

> $template

Any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as expected because you use single quotes in your string literal and single quotes don't expand variables - you just get a string consisting of variable name preceded by '$'. Instead, you can use:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml($template);
```

If you want to use your template as a part of loaded html, you should use double quotes, for example:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml("Personal data: <br>$template");
```

Variables in double-quoted strings are expanded.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue